# How to know a winsock has completed receiving file?

Tags: vb6, winsock

I'm using the `Winsock` control:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Winsock1.Connect "stackoverflow.com", 80
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Close()
  Winsock1.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_Connect()
  Winsock1.SendData "GET /questions/8624871/vb6-alternative-to-inet-webbrowser-control HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Host: stackoverflow.com" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
  Dim s As String

  Winsock1.GetData s, vbString
  RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & s
End Sub
```

How can I know that the control has completed receiving the file when the header doesn't contain `Content-Length`?

I've heard of some ways, like when `Winsock1.state` is `0` it means that the connection is closed, but sometimes it remains in some other state, like `7`, so I need another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to roll your own HTTP client, you should read the HTTP spec rather than guessing.

HTTP transfers use the Content-Length header to determine the length of the data. If the header is missing, then the end of data is signalled by the connection closing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the received HTTP headers. [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) explains how they tell you the length of the data and how the data needs to be read.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of components you can use in VB6 for making HTTP requests.  Some come with VB6, some are part of Windows now.  Most of these are far better than rolling your own HTTP on top of TCP using the Winsock control.  Header processing is just one of the things they can assist you in.